# using sql create a new table with 2 fields, field1 from tableA and field1 from table B

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Am new to SQL and am stuck here with a very simple-looking query request.

I have 2 tables, both having exactly the same structure (IE same no. of columns, same no. Of rows) except for the actual contents. so for example,tableA has 2 columns called col1&col2; tableB has 2 columns too called col1&col2. Now I want to create a 3rd new tale, where 1st column is tableA's col1, and 2nd column is tableB's col1. preferably the name of the 1st column is fromTableA, and name of 2nd column is fromTableC. How do I achieve this please? I tried all the following ways but I always get the same error: "number of query values and destination fields are not the same."

variation 1:

```
insert into newTable(fromTable1,fromTable2)
select col1 from table1
select col1 from table2
```

variation 2:

```
insert into newTable(fromTable1,fromTable2)
select col1 from table1,col1 from table2
```

variation 3:

```
insert into newTable(fromTable1,fromTable2)
select col1 from table1, table2
```

Comment: Is No of records on both the tables are equal? Is there any relation between those two tables, like col1 of tableA equals col1 of tableB?

Comment: How will you know how to match rows between TableA and TableB?

Comment: hi Paul and Prakash, no there's no relationship between the 2 tables. they have identical row numbers and even column numbers. basically the 2 tables are only matched by rows (row1 to row1, row2 to row2 etc)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have fields in the two tables that can be joined, so this:

insert into newtable (romTable1,fromTable2)
select a.col1, b.col1
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.col1 = b.col1;

The a/b are aliases that differentiate between the two columns in each table. If you don't have fields to join then whatever you're trying to do probably needs a rethink.

Comment: thx Evopop, I tried this in access but it complained that "could not find output table newtable". but of course this newtable doesn't exist yet cos we're looking to create it with this statement(how silly of access!)! how do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You may try following sql query to achieve your purpose:

```
with OrderedTableA as (
select row_number() over (order by Col1) RowNum, *
from TableA (nolock)
),
OrderedTableB as (
    select row_number() over (order by Col1) RowNum, *
    from TableB (nolock)
)

select T1.Col1, T2.Col2 into TableC 
from OrderedTableA T1
    full outer join OrderedTableB T2 on T1.RowNum = T2.RowNum
```

Above query will create a new table as TableC with column col1 from  TableA and col2 from TableB. You may change the queries to your need.
I hope you will understand the above queries. Give it a try.

Comment: hi Prakash thx for ur suggeston. I tried it in access but realize got syntax error so I looked up on internet and they say access does NOT recognize "row_number()" function. my guess is access sql is really basic. but ur idea prompted me I could simply add an ID column (with simple row numbers in them) and then join the 2 tables.

Comment: @user3164815 Cool, go ahead. Mark it as answer or vote up as it helped.